# SonarPython no vulnerability rules?

Tags: sonarqube

it appears as if sonarqube doesn't look for any vulnerabilities in python code by default: https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/type/Vulnerability is this the intended behaviour? what is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarPython has some rules which used to be categorized as "vulnerabilities" and are now considered as "security hotspots". You can check the [list of security hotspots](https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/type/Security%20Hotspot).